Drop Down Menu seperator
Been searching for a solution for days, couldn't find one. I did an approach by adding the menu entries inside a container and gave the bottom border. But the issue arises when the item is selected, it appears along with the border in the selected box. I use DropDownButton2, and now I don't see a dropDownSeperator, as there used to be one. How would I tackle this? I did try to control the border with a variable and set the border to transparent if it was selected, but that item from the menu entries loses its border too
DropdownButton2<int>(
                            onMenuStateChange: (bool value) {
                              BlocProvider.of<MenuAvailabilityBloc>(context)
                                  .add(DropDownTappedEvent(
                                      isDropDownClosed: value));
                            },
                            items: [
                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: 0,
                                  child: Container(
                                      width: 150,
                                      padding:
                                          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          border: Border(
                                              bottom: BorderSide(
                                                  color: selectedValue ==
                                                              0 &&
                                                          !isDropDownClosed
                                                      ? Colors.transparent
                                                      : appBloc
                                                          .state
                                                          .appTheme
                                                          .fieldBorder))),
                                      child: const Text('1'))),
                            ],
                            value: selectedValue,
                            isExpanded: true,
                            iconStyleData: IconStyleData(
                                icon:
                                    SvgPicture.asset(eSvgAssets.downArrow)),
                            onChanged: (int? newValue) {
                              BlocProvider.of<MenuAvailabilityBloc>(context)
                                  .add(NewValueSelectEvent(
                                      selectedValue: newValue!));
                            },
                            menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 0, vertical: 0)),
                            dropdownStyleData: const DropdownStyleData(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                                width: 150,
                                decoration:
                                    BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white)),
                          ),


please provide any snippet code that you have tried

and if possible, please include the current visual that you have tried, so the people are not confused about your question

Says I cant post image yet

you can loop through items and skip divider on last index. also if it is ok you can use Popupmenu with PopupMenuDivider

To create a separator in DropdownButton2, you need to add an element that will act as your separator:
const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
         enabled: false,
         child: Divider(),
),

You can view the full example here or below:

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<String> items = [
    'Item1',
    'Item2',
    'Item3',
    'Item4',
  ];
  String? selectedValue;

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _addDividersAfterItems(List<String> items) {
    final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [];
    for (final String item in items) {
      menuItems.addAll(
        [
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: item,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                item,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //If it's last item, we will not add Divider after it.
          if (item != items.last)
            const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              enabled: false,
              child: Divider(),
            ),
        ],
      );
    }
    return menuItems;
  }

  List<double> _getCustomItemsHeights() {
    final List<double> itemsHeights = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < (items.length * 2) - 1; i++) {
      if (i.isEven) {
        itemsHeights.add(40);
      }
      //Dividers indexes will be the odd indexes
      if (i.isOdd) {
        itemsHeights.add(4);
      }
    }
    return itemsHeights;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton2<String>(
            isExpanded: true,
            hint: Text(
              'Select Item',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
              ),
            ),
            items: _addDividersAfterItems(items),
            value: selectedValue,
            onChanged: (String? value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedValue = value;
              });
            },
            buttonStyleData: const ButtonStyleData(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              height: 40,
              width: 140,
            ),
            dropdownStyleData: const DropdownStyleData(
              maxHeight: 200,
            ),
            menuItemStyleData: MenuItemStyleData(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              customHeights: _getCustomItemsHeights(),
            ),
            iconStyleData: const IconStyleData(
              openMenuIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


